# Problems with QByteArray::right

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, byte

i have a problem with the right function of QByteArray. I dont konw what i am doing wronge. I dont understand why the output is like it is. In my mind in the first Output example the line between xxxx and ----- should be 4080-1897 so 2183.
Could someone tell me what is wrong?

```
    QByteArray serialByteBuffer; //serialByteBuffer is already filled
    unsigned char start_stop = 0xFE;
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    if(serialByteBuffer.count(start_stop)==2){

    qDebug()<< "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    qDebug()<< serialByteBuffer.size();
    qDebug()<< "+++++++++++++";
    int z = serialByteBuffer.indexOf(start_stop);
    qDebug()<< z;
    qDebug()<< "xxxxxxxxxxxxx+";
    QByteArray y = serialByteBuffer.right(z);
    qDebug() << y.size();
    qDebug()<< "---------------";


    serialByteBuffer.clear();
}
```

Output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
8160
+++++++++++++
2111
xxxxxxxxxxxxx+
2111
---------------
```

or

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
4080
+++++++++++++
1897
xxxxxxxxxxxxx+
1897
---------------
```

or ...

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the documentation about [`QByteArray::right()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#right).

This function takes a length as parameter so that:

> Returns a byte array that contains the rightmost len bytes of this byte array.

Consequently, when you writes:

> ```
> QByteArray y = serialByteBuffer.right(z);
> ```

Then, (the value of) `z` **is** `y.size()`. You got the expected results of what you wrote.

`z` and `y.size()` may differ if `z` exceeds the size of the `serialByteBuffer` byte array as mentioned in the documentation:

> The entire byte array is returned if len is greater than size().

Comment: I think the right side of the Array should be 8160-1897 long. so y .size() shouldnt be the same as z.      If i use left instead of right z and y.size() are the same too.

Comment: @MB1995 No you don't understand. Look at the documentation example. `x.right(5)` means _"return the 5 last bytes of `x`"_ which gives "apple" (size 5) from "pineapple" (size 9). You can easily see that the size is definitely not `9-5` but `5`. `right()` does not remove the right part but does return the right part. You misunderstood the usage of this function I'm afraid :)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. now i got it. thanks :)